# Disable certain org mode markup

Tags: emacs, markdown, markup, org-mode

I want to be able to disable strikethrough happening when I type `+` in an org-mode document. Specifically it is for entries in a table. Is there an easy way of doing this for a specific org-mode document since I only want to disable it for one document in particular. If not a way to toggle this would be nice.

I know I can have a literal `+` symbol with `\plus` but I would like to be able to see it in the document rather than reading the `\plus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `org-emphasis-alist` for just one file:

```
-*- org-emphasis-alist: nil -*-

+not struckout+
```

Of course, this removes all emphasis (bold, italic, etc.).  I cannot figure out how to remove just strikeout in just one file (specifically, I can't figure out how to delete an element of the alist locally).

Comment: I just reassigned the alist with what I needed which was only bold at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

To disable strikethrough in a specific file, add the following to your file:

```
-*- org-emphasis-alist: (("*" bold) ("/" italic) ("_" underline) ("=" org-verbatim verbatim) ("~" org-code verbatim) ("+" (:strike-through nil))); -*-
```

The down-side is that it will complain that the file may contain values that are not safe (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html#Safe-File-Variables)). You can also use the longer version at the bottom of your file, as mentioned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).

To do it for *all* your org files is a simpler, and will not ask questions:

```
(setq org-emphasis-alist (quote (("*" bold "<b>" "</b>")
                                 ("/" italic "<i>" "</i>")
                                 ("_" underline "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">" "</span>")
                                 ("=" org-code "<code>" "</code>" verbatim)
                                 ("~" org-verbatim "<code>" "</code>" verbatim))))
```

Sources: [Bernt Hansen's org-mode notes](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#StrikeThroughEmphasis)(a must-read) and [the org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve this by defining an overlay (`+`) for the literal plus (`\plus`). There is a library called "Auto Overlays" that

> allows you to define overlays that are created (and updated and destroyed) automatically when text in a buffer matches a regular expression

(quoted from the home page of the author).

You can download a standalone version of the library from [here](http://www.dr-qubit.org/emacs.php#overlay-download). If you are on Emacs 24 and have the [Marmalade Repo](http://marmalade-repo.org) enabled, you can install the `predictive` package via

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `predictive` <kbd>RET</kbd>

which apparently includes "Auto Overlays".

The documentation for this library is [here](http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/auto-overlay-manual/html/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by using local variables in the file

```
# Local Variables:
# org-emphasis-alist: (everything but strike through)
# End:
```